# flickity groupCells functionality in react based carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, flickity

Can you please share a React carousel library that has same functionality as flickity's groupCells, client requirement is to differentiate active slides styles while still having inactive (satellites) slides visible. Flickity is jquery based, I was hoping to find something newer and more React style, but from the docs of the most popular https://bashooka.com/coding/15-react-carousel-gallery-image-slider-libraries/ libs I cannot see them to have it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a react based flickity library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flickity-component

Comment: yes but this is just a wrapper for jquery, not sure if it is production ready, perhaprs there is something like that written in react?